# jQuery Datatables: Why my column filter select isn't showing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have included a column filter in my jquery datatables, but it isn't loading. I will post my code below.

**CODE:**

```
var oTable = $('#big_table').dataTable({
  "aoColumnDefs": [{
    "sWidth": "20%",
    "aTargets": [6]
  }],
  "bProcessing": true,
  "aaSorting": [
    [0, 'desc']
  ],
  "bServerSide": true,
  "sAjaxSource": '<?php echo base_url(); ?>agent/order/list_order',
  "bJQueryUI": true,
  "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
  "iDisplayStart ": 25,
  "oLanguage": {
    "sProcessing": "<img src='<?php echo base_url(); ?>img/ajax-loader.gif'>"
  },
  "fnInitComplete": function() {
    //oTable.fnAdjustColumnSizing();
  },
  "fnRowCallback": function(nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex) {
    nRow.className = aData[5];
  },
  'fnServerData': function(sSource, aoData, fnCallback) {
    $.ajax({
      'dataType': 'json',
      'type': 'POST',
      'url': sSource,
      'data': aoData,
      'success': fnCallback
    });
  }
})
dataTable.columnFilter({
  sPlaceHolder: "head:before",
  aoColumns: [null, {
    type: "select",
    values: ['-01-', '-02-', '-03-', '-04-', '-05-', '-06-', '-07-', '-08-', '-09-', '-10-', '-11-', '-12-']
  },
              null,
              null,
              null,
              null,
              null,
             ]
});
```

That is the js code, I will post the includes from my header file as well.

```
<script src="<?php echo site_url('js/datatables/jquery.dataTables.js'); ?>"></script>
<script src="<?php echo site_url('js/datatables/jquery.dataTables.columnFilter.js'); ?>"></script>
```

Comment: `oTable.columnFilter({...})`?

Comment: I think that solved it, the only issue is the drop down comes onto the column name. `sPlaceHolder: "head:before",` is there any issue with the above code?